# Json4s casting error during string parsing

Tags: scala, json4s

```
final case class Stuff(metadata: Option[String]) {
val metadataJson: JObject = parse(metadata.getOrElse("{}")).asInstanceOf[JObject]
}
```

This throws a type mismatch error

found: Object

required: JsonInput

But it shouldnt happen since metadata.getOrElse.. should be type String which is casted to JsonInput

Answer (score 0):

Sooo it turns out that getorelse messes with implicit type conversion because it can technically return any type >: String

easy fix is just to specify type

```
parse(metadata.getOrElse[String]("{}")).asInstanceOf[JObject]
```